# How to use useContext in a pure typescript class component(.ts)?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context

I having a pure typescript class component. I have created a context that can be used anywhere, and I wanted to know how to use context in .ts class component then if possible to use in pure typescript component.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `context.Consumer` to get the context's value in a class component. It follows the [render-props](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html) pattern.

```
interface ContextProps {
  property1: string;
}

const context = React.createContext<ContextProps | null>(null);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <context.Provider value={{ property1: '123' }}>
          <context.Consumer>
            {({ property1 }) => <div>{property1}</div>}
          </context.Consumer>
        </context.Provider>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this one but I asking pure typescript component not .tsx compoent in .ts component don't have a return write then how we can use the context?

Comment: @DineshV It's not clear what you are trying to achieve. Can you provide an example about `pure typescript component not .tsx component`

Comment: @ArdalanNahavandi I mean the extension of the component.

Comment: @DineshV I'm not sure if I understood correctly but the file extension in order to be able to use `JSX` syntax with typescript must be `.tsx`. You can't use `JSX` in a `.ts` file.